Canceling The Context Returned By WithTimeout() Also Cancels Parent Context
I have the following two methods:
func DeleteSessionId(id string, ctx *context.Context) (err error) {
    sqlStatement := "DELETE FROM sessions WHERE id = $1"
    queryCtx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(*ctx, 60*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    _, err = Constants.Db.ExecContext(queryCtx, sqlStatement, id)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("An error occured while deleting session from sessions table: " + err.Error())
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func DeleteAllSpecificUserSessionIds(userId string, ctx context.Context) (err error) {
    sqlStatement := "SELECT id from sessions where userid = $1"
    queryCtx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 60*time.Second)
    sqlRows, err := Constants.Db.QueryContext(queryCtx, sqlStatement, userId)
    cancel()

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("An error occurred when selecting sessions from DB: " + err.Error())
        return err
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for sqlRows.Next() {
        wg.Add(1)
        var sessionId string

        if err := sqlRows.Scan(&sessionId); err != nil {
            log.Println("An error occurred when looping through sessions from DB: " + err.Error())
            return err
        }

        var key = CacheKeys.SessionIdKey{
            SessionId: sessionId,
        }

        go func() {
            Constants.Cache.Remove(key)
            DeleteSessionId(sessionId, &ctx)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()

    if err := sqlRows.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Println("An error occurred when selecting sessions from DB: " + err.Error())
        return err
    }

    sqlRows.Close()
    return nil
}

When I call cancel() instead of using defer.Cancel(), the DeleteSessionId() method runs successfully only one time and subsequent calls fail with context cancelled. So, if there are 5 session Ids in the database, only one is deleted.
However, when I use defer.Cancel(), the DeleteSessionId() method runs successfully for all the iterations. So, if there are 5 session Ids in the database, all of them are deleted:
func DeleteSessionId(id string, ctx *context.Context) (err error) {
    sqlStatement := "DELETE FROM sessions WHERE id = $1"
    queryCtx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(*ctx, 60*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    _, err = Constants.Db.ExecContext(queryCtx, sqlStatement, id)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("An error occured while deleting session from sessions table: " + err.Error())
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func DeleteAllSpecificUserSessionIds(userId string, ctx context.Context) (err error) {
    sqlStatement := "SELECT id from sessions where userid = $1"
    queryCtx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 60*time.Second)
    sqlRows, err := Constants.Db.QueryContext(queryCtx, sqlStatement, userId)
    defer cancel()

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("An error occurred when selecting sessions from DB: " + err.Error())
        return err
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for sqlRows.Next() {
        wg.Add(1)
        var sessionId string

        if err := sqlRows.Scan(&sessionId); err != nil {
            log.Println("An error occurred when looping through sessions from DB: " + err.Error())
            return err
        }

        var key = CacheKeys.SessionIdKey{
            SessionId: sessionId,
        }

        go func() {
            Constants.Cache.Remove(key)
            DeleteSessionId(sessionId, &ctx)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()

    if err := sqlRows.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Println("An error occurred when selecting sessions from DB: " + err.Error())
        return err
    }

    sqlRows.Close()
    return nil
}

When I looked up the documentation for the context.WithTimeout() method, the docs do not mention anything about a copy of the parent context being created. I took this to assume that the context.Context returned by context.WithTimeout() refers to the parent context still. If this assumption is right, then calling cancel() at position 1 should cause all of my DeleteSessionId() method calls to fail. However, that's not what happens. As I already mentioned, the DeleteSessionId() method runs successfully once and deletes a single row from my table and then subsequent calls fail. I would like to know why this is the case.

Unrelated: there is no reason to pass pointer to Context around. Context is an interface and pointers to interfaces are almost always a mistake. Also, from the package docs: "Programs that use Contexts should follow these rules to keep interfaces consistent across packages and enable static analysis tools to check context propagation: [...] The Context should be the first parameter, typically named ctx."

I have found the solution to my problem. My issue was with my interpretation of how QueryContext worked. According to this github issue raised here, the result set from the database is not all received until you have completed iterating through the sqlrows set. So if you call cancel immediately after initializing sqlRows, when you go to scan a row in the for loop, you will get the context cancelled error.
This behaviour is not mentioned in the documentation for multiple rows database querying which lead me to believe my issue was with my understanding of the context.WithTimeout() method. In fact the wording of the documentation seems to imply that the entire dataset is returned after calling QueryContext.
Seems people are just downvoting the question even though they were unable to assist with finding the solution. Hopefully the documentation for the QueryContext method will be updated to make this more clear to future readers.

An often untold  feature of such database queries is that the query operation usually returns a cursor, and the cursor itself actually runs the query and fetches the results in batches. So db transactions should be kept open until all results are retrieved.

The WithTimeout doc states:

WithTimeout returns WithDeadline(parent, time.Now().Add(timeout)).

The WithDeadline doc states (emphasis mine):

WithDeadline returns a copy of the parent context with the deadline adjusted to be no later than d. If the parent's deadline is already earlier than d, WithDeadline(parent, d) is semantically equivalent to parent. The returned [Context.Done] channel is closed when the deadline expires, when the returned cancel function is called, or when the parent context's Done channel is closed, whichever happens first.

That means WithTimeout returns a new Context. Per the package documentation (again, emphasis mine):

The WithCancel, WithDeadline, and WithTimeout functions take a Context (the parent) and return a derived Context (the child) and a CancelFunc. Calling the CancelFunc cancels the child and its children, removes the parent's reference to the child, and stops any associated timers.

So cancelling a context cancels all children (contexts derived from it) but not its parent (the context it was drived from).

This is correct. Just want to add that this also means that if the parent context is cancelled, the new derived context will be cancelled. The WithTimeout method does return a new context, but it is still dependent on the parent context. I only point this out to make sure readers understand that when we say "a new context" this doesn't mean a totally new context like you get from context.TODO().
